# Type can be array or number, getting 'implicitly has any type' error

Tags: typescript

I have an interface that can either acccept a `number` or an `array` as a value. The array always has a number first, then a string like `[136237, "Name of something"]`.

I have the type set like this:

```
interface SaleOrder {
  ...,
  partner_id?: [number, string] | number;`
}
```

In this use case, the property comes in as an array.

In my code, I have:

```js
const { name, partner_id, id, amount_total } = saleOrder as SaleOrder;

const order = {
      "Name": name as string,
      "Customer Name": partner_id[1] as string,
      "Total Sale": amount_total as number
    }
```

And I'm showing this warning is vs code:
[image]

Of course property '1' can be used to index an array, so why the warning?

Comment: Because `partner_id` may be a number and you can't index into a number.

Comment: ok so I guess I need to do `const partner_id = saleOrder.partner_id as [number, string]` first

Comment: Instead of casting the type it would be better to check whether the entry is an array or a number, how can you be sure otherwise?

Comment: You should think about what happens if `partner_id` is a number and then assign your customername accordingly for both cases or at least check. And something tells me, your typing needs a few enhancements, because using `as ...` in every assignment somehow defeats the purpose of typescript

Comment: I'm sure in this case it's an array because that's how the data comes every time when making an API call.  The other castings are just because I know they aren't undefined here. I guess I could make a separate type for when it's an API call and a different one when a record is being created and some of those fields are optional.

Comment: @chuckieDub That would be better, yes, since then your types actually match the real data. Otherwise having types loses a lot of its value.

Answer (score 0):

Error occurs because You're not checking if `partner_id` is an array, or a number. `Property '1' does not exist on type 'number | [number, string]'` is prompted, because there's no '1' property in `number` type, it can exists only in array.

You should avoid casting as much as possible. You may be sure that object you're receiving from API is contains array, but typescript at time of compilation has no such assurance. Instead, implement checks like in example below:

```js
interface SaleOrder {
  partner_id?: [number, string] | number;
}

const saleOrder: SaleOrder = {
  partner_id: [1, 'text']
};
const { partner_id } = saleOrder;

const order = {
  "Customer Name": Array.isArray(partner_id) ? partner_id[1] : 'unknown name', //I'm not sure what you want to return as a fallback.
}
```

playground:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMpwDYQPJQCbTIDeAUMsgA5xRgjQD6weA-AFzIDaIArgLYBG0ADTIAzmCigA5gF1kAH2Q8B0ANwkAviRIIA9iHFjMOfNHbosuAlGQBeYmUrVaDJuw4BGEQHJIADzBvGU11PQMwYicaOihGPGQNOyNLUyh1HX1DXVSk0nIAIgBhbnFdXkIAOThy-PYAQSgoOABPADpgUQam5oAKKmjXPABKZGYol1imTzl2fom4oU0SIA